# Scrapy response 403 set request.dont_filter False

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

im currently scraping https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/results

this site use a cookie ('datadome') that expires given some time, then after all requests responses are 403 until it stops. currently using JOB_DIR in setting.py for persistent data between crawls. 
Once I update the cookie start the crawler again but 403s pages are omitted because of duplicate requests already done to the site.

Is there a way to set dont_filter once i get the response?

ive tried the following using download middleware with no luck.

```
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

    #if response.status == 403:
    #    print(request.url,"expired cookie")
    #    request.dont_filter=True

    return response
```

Manipulate requests seen url seem an option too but i dont find any hint on how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your use case but to answer your question: you can reschedule a request in downloader middleware. Make sure it's priority is high in your settings and in `process_response` return a new modified request:

```py
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if response.status == 403:
        print(request.url,"expired cookie")
        request.dont_filter=True
        return request
    return response
```

As per documentation if `process_response` returns a request it will be rescheduled however if you return response it will continue to be processed through the middlewares and returned to your callback.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response

> If it returns a Response (it could be the same given response, or a brand-new one), that response will continue to be processed with the process_response() of the next middleware in the chain.
>
> If it returns a Request object, the middleware chain is halted and the returned request is rescheduled to be downloaded in the future. This is the same behavior as if a request is returned from process_request().

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the link, however now I need to check what to do after I return a request or ignore request. probably it will be better to return an exception and handle with errback callback but I need to check if Scrapy will still visit the same page again once I run the spider again.

Comment: @FranciscoVaras You can always replace `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` setting with your own class with your dupe strategy; see: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class

Comment: Thanks a lot , will check the documentation.